Listening to realtime changes to objects stored in a Firestore Document
I am moving my app from Realtime Database (RTDB) to Firestore. I have some questions regarding structuring data for some objects. In Realtime Database, we could essentially listen to real-time changes at any level but in Firestore, we can only listen to real-time changes in a collection or a document. For example, I have the following data in RTDB

The images object contains the user's profile image. This image can be seen by the user in their profile and also as the contact image for users who have this user as a contact. When the image is updated by the user, the contact image is updated automatically. So, we listen to changes to the image object and update the images when it changes.
While moving it to Firestore, I copied it over as follows:

But now I am not able to only listen to changes to the images object and update the contact image. Rather, I have to listen to changes to the whole userInfo object and update images when there is any change to the userInfo object. The userInfo object tracks a bunch of things, so the change handler will be called many times.
I am thinking that I should probably store the images as a top-level collection, and store images for each user and listen to the images document for the user. I wanted to know if that is a better approach to storing images and if there is a general guideline to store objects that a client needs to listen to in a Firestore document. There are many such objects that may change in real time which were working fine in the below data model in RTDB but proving to be challenging in Firestore.

To understand better, do you need to be informed only when the images (field) inside the document is changed?

There are multiple pieces of information which when updated should trigger some code to handle the update. The trouble I am having is that if I simply listen to userInfos/{userId}, all these update handlers will be triggered again and again leading me to rethink the data model. Some of the data stored in userInfo is updated very frequently such as alarmCounts. This is a huge migration that I have taken up. There are around 5 million user records storing over 25 GBs of data in the RTDB. This was done way before Firestore was introduced but it has become very costly now and need to migrate.

@AlexMamo Forgot to add your name, so adding a new comment. The app is a collaborative app and relies heavily on realtime updates to update the app automatically for affected users. Since, I can't listen to changes to an object within a Firestore document, I am trying to find out what is the best approach in general to handle such cases data-model-wise.

Storing the images as a separate (top-level or nested) collection is indeed the common solution to allow you to listen to changes in that specific part of your data.


Since I can't listen to changes to an object within a Firestore document, I am trying to find out what is the best approach in general to handle such cases data-model-wise.

Yes, that is correct. You cannot get only a slice of a document, that's not possible using the web or mobile client SDKs. Firebase listeners fire on the document level, so you can read the entire document or nothing.
The best option that you have, in such cases, is to denormalize the data. This means that you can store the images in a separate collection or sub-collection in Firestore, or you can save the same denormalized data in the Realtime Database. The latter would be the preferred solution as it provides the ability to attach a listener and get real-time updates only from a specific part of your data.

By the latter approach, you mean that I continue to save some part of the data in Realtime Database such that I can easily attach listeners and get real-time updates from specific part of data without having to create too many collection/sub-collections?

Yes, that's exactly what I meant.

Yes, I have accepted the answer. Thanks for your help!
